# capitalize a textfield but only when I click on a button in flutter

Tags: flutter, capitalization

I need to be able to capitalize an entire textfield with writing in it when I click on a button, however when I kept searching the internet for a solution I couldn't find one, please help.

Comment: use TextEditingController and string.toUpper()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is set the `TextEditingController.text` to its content, but with a call to `.toUpperCase()`.

```dart
controller.text = controller.text.toUpperCase();
```

Here's an example app (which you can try on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/flutter)):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        TextField(
          controller: _controller,
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text('toUpperCase()'),
          onPressed: () {
            _controller.text = _controller.text.toUpperCase();
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```